# select gridview rows bases on status without sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with 2 columns.

NAME STATUS

TEST | YES

TEST1| NO

Gridview is bound from xml file.

Now my issue is how can I select row which have status YES. and Mail those rows only. Emailing part I can do. Issue is how to get rows with status YES. As sql is not used here.

Comment: You can do it on the underlying xml with Linq

Comment: I'm a newbie. can u please give a small example

Comment: Not without knowing your datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do that.

```
var yesitem = gridviewlist.Where(a => a.Status == YES).FirstOrDefault();
```

**yesitem** will have the item which has YES status. Then you can email it as per your requirement. Or if you want the name only, do as below code

```
string name = gridviewlist.Where(a => a.Status == YES).Select(a => a.NAME).FirstOrDefault();
```